# Datatable in java

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I am having below xml data which I need to put in mysql database. Right now Im reading the tag name and values individually to put the data in DB. Can anyone help me if there is something like datatable to generate table directly using the mydata.xml and store in database.

```
\\ mydata.xml
<arbitrarytag xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="#local">
    <xs:schema id="local">
        <xs:element name="root">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="qty" type="xs:integer" />
                    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="date" type="xs:dateTime" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <root>
        <qty>25</qty>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <date>1972-08-30T00:00:00+05:30</date>
    </root>
</arbitrarytag>
```

Below code where Im parsing the xml and fetching the data.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("mydata.xml");
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
Node n = nList.item(0);
Element ele = (Element) nNode;
String tag = ele.getNodeName();
String val = ele.getChildNodes().item("qty").getTextContent();
```

Is there any way to create table using mydata.xml and store in database

Answer (score 0):

## Importing XML file into MySQL Table

If you only want to import the XML data into MySQL database you might use [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html). Here is an example how this done:

1. Create the XML file and save it in directory on your file system, let us say on `/tmp` directory on Linux system. So I have created a file named `mydata.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <root>
       <qty>25</qty>
       <firstname>John</firstname>
       <some_date>1972-08-30T00:00:00+05:30</some_date>
   </root>
   ```
2. Create a table in the database, say `tab1` as:

   ```
   create table tab1 (qty int, firstname varchar(30), some_date datetime);
   ```
3. Execute the following statement on MySQL console:

   ```
   mysql> load xml local infile '/tmp/mydata.xml' into table tab1 rows identified by '<root>';
   ```

where `/tmp/mydata.xml` is the path to the XML file (in my case in the tmp directory on Linux system).

And here is the result, if you did as I described:

> mysql> select * from tab1;
>
> +------+-----------+---------------------+
>
> | qty  | firstname | some_date           |
>
> +------+-----------+---------------------+
>
> |   25 | John      | 1972-08-30 00:00:00 |
>
> +------+-----------+---------------------+
>
> 1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Note: The offset in the timestamp is just truncated while importing. If this is important look at MySQL documentation how to do it correctly.